# How to filter the main data based on list available after filter using angular2

Tags: angular

i have main list called tenants, so based on checkbox checked i need to filter the tenants list based on leaseLists year. So, if the lease list of tenants object lies in current year then that particular tenants must be shown or it must be hidden.
Filtering of leaseLists has been done. Can anyone help me to filter the main tenants list based on filtered leaseList.
If checkbox is unchecked, then full lists should be displayed.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-8" id="current-tenant-toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" class="cursor" id="current-tenant"   (change)="selectValue($event)" /><label
    class="cursor"
    for="current-tenant" 
    >Only current tenants</label
  >
</div>
```

Please Find Working Demo:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ut3dt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Did I undestand correctly: If a tenants "leaseList" array includes a date that is current year, the tenant should be shown when the checkbox is checked?

Comment: ya correct, this is what i need

Comment: now the filtering of lease list is happening selectedMembers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved your issue,

you have to make below changes in you app.component.html page

```
    <div class="col-md-8" id="current-tenant-toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cursor" id="current-tenant"   (change)="selectValue($event)" />
    <label class="cursor"
        for="current-tenant" 
        >Only current tenants</label
      >
</div>
<div class="" id="tenant-list">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 accordion-grid ">
            <div>
                <div *ngFor="let tenant of selectedMembers; let i = index">
                    <div>
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-2">Suite</div>
                                <div class="col-2 accordion-grid-col">{{ tenant.suite }}</div>
                                <div class="col-3">Company Name</div>
                                <div class="col-3 accordion-grid-col">
                    {{ tenant.companyName }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2">Sq Ft</div>
                                <div class="col-2 accordion-grid-col">{{ tenant.sqFt }}</div>

                                <div class="col-3">Contact Name</div>
                                <div class="col-3 accordion-grid-col">
                    {{ tenant.contactName }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2">Action</div>
                                <div class="col-2 accordion-grid-col">
                                    <div>
                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil action"  title="Edit" (click)="editTenant($event, tenant)">
                                        </i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-trash action" title="Delete" (click)="deleteTenant($event, tenant.id, i)">
                                        </i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and also make changes in app.component.ts file, make selectedMembers variables to globle in your ts file

```
selectedMembers: any[]; 

ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedMembers = this.tenants;
  }

  selectValue(evt) {
    selectedMembers = []
    console.log(evt.isTrusted)
    if(evt.isTrusted){
    console.log(this.tenants, "this.tenants")
    let startDate = new Date().getFullYear();
    this.tenants.map(obj => {
      if (obj.leaseList.length) {
        let chckorthecurrentDate=false
        obj.leaseList.map(
          m => {
            if (new Date(m.dateEnd).getFullYear() == startDate) {
            chckorthecurrentDate=true
            }
          })
          if(chckorthecurrentDate){
             chckorthecurrentDate=false
            selectedMembers.push(obj)
          }
      }
    })
    console.log(selectedMembers)
  } else {
    this.selectedMembers = this.tenants;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put *ngFor in a `<ng-container>` element and then use *ngIf in a `<div>` element like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let tenant of tenants; let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="leaseIsCurrentYear(tenant)">
        ....
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Use `leaseIsCurrentYear(tenant)` method to test the dates if the current tenant should be visible.

I hope this helps you!